# PDFMarks Initial View Magnification to FitPage

Tags: pdf-generation, ghostscript

I am using ghost script to convert my postscript file to PDF/A.

Below is the command to generate the PDF/A file

```
gs -q -dPDFA=2 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOOUTERSAV -sProcessColorModel=DeviceGray \
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFastWebView=true -dPSFitPage  -dDOPDFMARKS \
   -sOutputFile=NewPDF.pdf PDFA_def.ps abc.ps pdfmarks
```

The PDFMarks file looks like:

```
[ /Title (Document title)
  /DOCINFO pdfmark

[ /Page 1 /Title (COVER PAGE) /OUT pdfmark
[ /PageMode /UseOutlines /View [/FitPage]/Page 1 /DOCVIEW pdfmark
[ {Catalog} <</ViewerPreferences<</DisplayDocTitle true>>/PageLayout/OneColumn>> /PUT pdfmark
```

Still when the PDF/A generates, the Magnification Property is set to Default Only. I need to set it to FitPage.

I tried using /Fit,/FitB,/FitH etc but none of them seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

There is no '`FitPage`', using this option causes Acrobat to raise a warning when opening the resulting PDF file (Ghostscript does not attempt to fully validate pdfmark operands)

`Fit` uses the CropBox to determine the scaling, and you haven't specified a CropBox so unless your other PostScript does so, then there won't be one. Similar problems may exist with the other options you have mentioned.

The PUT pdfmark is also incorrect, the '`<>`' should be '`<<`'.

You do not need (and should not use) `-dNOOUTERSAVE`.

I wouldn't use `-dFastWSebView` unless you have a very good reason, it simply takes longer to process and produces a larger file for no really good reason.

`PSFitPage` won't do anything useful if you don't specify a fixed media size (which you haven't).

You don't need `-dDOPDFMARKS`, that's for PDF input only (and in any event defaults to true).

If you want the PDF/A file to be Gray you should set `-sColorConversionStrategy=DeviceGray` rather than meddling with the `ProcessColorModel`.

I used a simple empty PostScript program and added:

```
[ /PageMode /UseOutlines /View [/FitV] /Page 1 /DOCVIEW pdfmark
```

The resulting PDF file displayed as expected.